# I/O Device Error on hpv236w 64gb USB

Tags: windows-10, usb

When I try to access my hpv236w 64gb USB, it gives me this error:'F:\ is not accessible. The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.' I can't format it too. I tried many steps to fix this but they were useless.

How can I fix this?

This information maybe of some use:
I am able to access and recover files on the drive when i turn on write-protect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should allow for the possibility there really *is* an I/O error and that the device really is defective. And if so, that's not something you can fix.

Comment: The stuff in the drive is still there. I don't think there is anything wrong with the USB. Also, write-protect is not the problem - I/O device error is. I really don't know why this question is marked as duplicate.